# What WindowManager.LayoutParams do I use if I want to receive all touch events on screen, but still be able to interact with views behind the Manager?

Tags: android, android-windowmanager

I am currently using this implemnetaion

```
LinearLayout touchLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        // set layout
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        touchLayout.setLayoutParams(lp);
        // set on touch listener
        touchLayout.setOnTouchListener(this);
        touchLayout.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
        touchLayout.setFocusable(false);
        touchLayout.setClickable(false);
        // fetch window manager object
        WindowManager mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        // set layout parameter of window manager
        WindowManager.LayoutParams mParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, // width is equal to full screen
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, // height is equal to full screen
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT , //
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, // this window won't ever get key input focus
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        mParams.gravity = Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP;
        mWindowManager.addView(touchLayout, mParams);
```

The only problem with this is that the user can't interact with anything behind the LinearLayout I placed.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the touchlistener on the root element of your active window or XML file then decide how/where to distribute the touch for your needs

Comment: That would work If i just needed to detect events within my own app, but I'm trying to be able to detect all touch events on the users device

Comment: oh haha, sounds hackerish, well you could implement a floating window service and run in the background. I have used this library to accomplish it in the past when i wrote an overlay for Clash of Clans https://github.com/pingpongboss/StandOut/blob/master/library/src/wei/mark/standout/StandOutWindow.java